# How do I register components in subfolders in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/components
  /sections
    /ImageGrid
      ImageGrid.vue
    /ContactSection
      ContactSection.vue
```

Within the Vue files I register the components with the `name` key. The name is equal to the file name (`"ImageGrid"`).

When I use `<component is="ImageGrid" />` I get the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ImageGrid> - did you register the component correctly?`

I tried adding the following lines to the Nuxt.config:

```
{ path: '~/components/sections', extensions: ['vue'] },
// Or:
{ path: '~/components/sections/**/*', extensions: ['vue'] },
```

How should the Nuxt.config be configured?

Answer (score 1):

This works with the following configuration in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  components: [
    { path: '~/components/sections', extensions: ['vue'] }
  ],
}
```

Any given page

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="componentId" />
    <button @click="swapComponents">SWAP THEM!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      componentId: 'ImageGrid',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponents() {
      this.componentId === 'ImageGrid'
        ? (this.componentId = 'ImageRow')
        : (this.componentId = 'ImageGrid')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

And the following structure

[image]

A demo can be seen here: https://share.cleanshot.com/dE2nFr

---

An official answer can be found here: https://github.com/nuxt/components/issues/227#issuecomment-902013353

---

Update: this simpler version also works of course

```html
<template>
  <component :is="'ImageGrid'" />
</template>
```